# odata and pivot control with several pivotitem controls

Tags: windows-phone-7, odata

my pivotitems each require different odata calls in order to populate data in them.

must i make all those calls when the pivot is intialized or is there a way to fire each call when the user flicks to that pivotitem?

Any example of this will be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may choose both approaches in different situations.

From user experience view, preload all data is always better. In this situation, when user scrolls to the next page data is already there. Note, that first page you must load as fast as you can (use some delay approaches for other pages, for example).

Write out all pros and cons that you achieve, and you make a right choice ;)